# get Docker error each time I reboot my machine: "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock."

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running on ubuntu 18.04 with docker version:

```
 >> docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.6
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.16
 Git commit:        369ce74a3c
 Built:             Thu Feb 13 01:27:48 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
```

each time I reboot my machine and try to use docker (e.g docker ps), I get an error:

```
>> docker ps   
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

after I run:

```
>> service docker stop
>> service docker start
```

everything is back to normal..

any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: @AbinavR It's not a permissions problem.

Answer (score 1):

you should run

```
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

it will configure the system to start the service at reboot

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer.
I did try it but it didn't help.

I see the service of docker is running (systemctl status docker.service) but still getting the same error